# Trying to query one sheet to inform another

Tags: google-sheets

Someone at the Google Docs Help Forum suggested I ask you guys about this project I'm working on.  See the whole (pretty short) thread [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/rpAFU0u7j7k/Y7bCGGzNDZMJ).

In essence, I'm just trying to find a simple query that counts the entries of a particular name for this month and last month and outputs the number of times that entry shows up in that date range.

Example: I'm trying to have `sheet#2` (and others) poll `sheet#1` to see what names have been entered and then aggregate the content.  Example: there are three separate entries for `John Doe` this month and five for last month, `Jane Doe` has six for this month and two for last month. `sheet#2` would then output:

```
John Doe, 3 this month, 5 last month, Jane Doe, 6 this month, 2 last month
```

and rank them based on the number of entries.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

Does Sheet1 have the month, or just a date.   If it doesn't have the month, can you make a helper column which contains the month.

Then from the Data menu, choose Pivot Table report.

Put Name into the Rows, and Month into the Columns (or vice versa), and then put Count of name into the values.